# What to do inorder to lock home directory in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

How do I lock the **home** directory of the administrator in Ubuntu such that other users do not have access to it?

Answer (score 0):

Using permissions. If you mean the home directory of the `root` user, their home should have `550` permissions, being the owner `root` and group `root`. That way, no `other` permissions are granted and therefore noone else has access to it.

### /root permissions

`dr-xr-x---.   8 root root  4096 may 15 09:16 root`

If you mean user permissions, a good decision would be have the `/home` directory with `755` permissions, so anyone can `cd` into it, and have each user's home directory with permissions only for themselves (`700`).

### /home directory permissions

`drwxr-xr-x.   5 root root  4096 abr 11  2018 home`

### Each user's home permissions

`drwx------. 6 user user  4096 ago 18  2017 user`

Comment: Perhaps should mention that the home directory of the user `root` is the directory `/root` and that it already has permissions set as `700` (owner only can read, write, execute). So, essentially the answer is "do nothing". But, if someone has physical access, unless the files are encrypted, they can just use a live OS on a pendrive and access the files anyway no matter how you set permissions.

Comment: note that this solution does not prevent access from a determined arty - especially not if they hace physical access ti the machine - in which case, sans additional measures, gaining access is trivial.

Comment: Can you please be clear, I am unable to understand your answer.

Comment: What clarification do you need concretely?